# How to Count as a 1 day if the dates are same in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have scenario which I would like to count as one day if the dates are same.

```xml
<wd:Date>2021-08-18</wd:Date>
<wd:Date>2021-08-18</wd:Date>
```

How can I achieve this using XSLT. So, I want count this a one day if the Date is same.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Take the difference and add 1?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- use `xs:date()` to evaluate those values as `xs:date`
- then subtract one date from the other to get the difference as `xs:dateTimeDuration`
- then use `days-from-duration()` to return that number of days (which would be zero)
- apply `abs()`, such that we don't have to worry about which date was on the left or right hand side and positive or negative values
- and then add `1` to that value

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Days: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="abs(days-from-duration(xs:date(/*/*:Date[1]) - xs:date(/*/*:Date[2]))) + 1"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this XML file:

```
<wd:example xmlns:wd="wd">
    <wd:Date>2021-08-18</wd:Date> 
    <wd:Date>2021-08-18</wd:Date>    
</wd:example>
```

Produces this output:

```
Days: 1
```